# JQUERY Datatable PageIndex change event

Tags: jquery, datatables

Friends,
Am only a newbie to jquery datatable which I found an awesome jquery plugin. So I was trying to integrate this with .NET and obviously because I was looking for a PageIndex changing or PageIndex changed event on the datatable. But unfortunately I didnt find something similar. So is there is any event for this plugin which executes when the page index changes?

I tried with binding the page event to the datatable. but it only worked when I click on the prev or next button. it didnt worked when clicking on the page numbers. Requesting your support

Thanks in advance

Comment: this? -> http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/#page

Comment: @FabioG The problem with Page method is it will only invoke at the next and prev button events

Answer (score 1):

the fnDrawCallback event is fired on every 'draw' event, hence when a page index has changed.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
    }
  } );
} );
```

Comment: This can be a solution, which I tried, but honestly didnt find this as an optimal way since fnDrawcallback will execute in lots of situations. Not just page index change...

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't an event that will fire on each page index change. 
You can bind the "Page" event to the datatables, but that will probably only work on next and prev button events.
`$(table).bind('page', function () {
   //console.log('page changed');
} );`